# Adding special characters (e.g. $) to double value in Identify window?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I don't know what I want is possible in ArcMap? I have a field whose type is "Double". The value in it is accurate to 2 decimal places. When I use Identify to see the detail information of a feature, I wonder whether there is a way to add a $ in front of the double value?

What I see in Identify is as follows:

[image: Identify window]

What I intend to see in the CONTRACT_SUM field is $24222568, is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved by setting the format of the field in ArcMap to Currency

Go to the layer properties > fields tab > Your CONTRACT_SUM field and set Number Format to Currency. It will use the symbol from the localized settings, so in my screenshot its £ but if you are American you will get $.

[image: Setting numeric format]

You will then observe the $ symbol in the Identify window.

Comment: Nice one Duncan...learn something everyday